# Is it possible to point my connection string to the folder of my exe file

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm making a windows forms project and I was wondering if its possible to point the connection string for my .mdf file to the folder of the programs .exe file so that when I send the program to my someone else it can still find the file.

This is what I'm using right now but I want it to point to the .exe file folder instead if possible.
I've tried everything I can find on this topic and I can't figure it out.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Martin\source\repos\Guldkortet\Guldkortet\Kortregister.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: SQL Server is *not* a file-based database. LocalDB is a [specialized feature of SQL Server Express meant mainly for development and testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16). If you install SQL Server Express, why use LocalDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that your database is in the folder of your main .exe file and you want to get the path, use `System.Reflection`, more specifically - the assembly's [Location property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location) to get the path at runtime, for example:

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

and construct the connection string using it:

```
string connectionString = String.Format("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={0}\\Kortregister.mdf;Integrated Security=True", assemblyPath);
```

There are other options, but that's the answer to your question.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do but I cant get that work with my connection string

Comment: Why? I've added the real string constructor using the data you provided. Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Kortregister.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

The `|DataDirectory|` placeholder will be resolved at run time and what it resolves to depends on the type of application. For a WinForms app, it will resolve to the program folder by default, including while debugging. If you copy your app to a different folder or different machine, it will just work. If you deploy using ClickOnce then a dedicated data directory is created outside the program folder and that path will be resolved correctly.

Note that, because no code is required to construct the connection string, it can be stored in a config file or the like. That means that a user can modify it after deployment if they want their database in a different place or, perhaps, permanently attached to an instance.

Comment: This does not work.  It gives me exception error:  {"Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'."} System.ArgumentException

Comment: @Rara.-., it was my understanding that you always need the slash before the file name but [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) indicates that you don't include a slash for SQL Server, where it indicates that you do for Access and some others. Try removing the slash and see whether that works. It's a while since I did this myself but I'm I have done it before with SQL Server Express and it has worked.